# Drawable offset

Tags: android

Добрый день, имеется такой xml

```
<layer-list>
        <item android:top="2dp">
            <shape
                   android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@color/btn_pressed_color"/>
            </shape>
        </item>

        <item android:bottom="2dp"
              android:top="2dp">
              <shape
                    android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@color/btn_normal_color"/>
              </shape>
        </item>
</layer-list>
```

Необходимо создать его программно, конкретно интересует `<item android:top="2dp">`

setPadding не помогает, что можно придумать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня есть класс который создавал программно ползунок для моей линии прокрутки. Он к сожалению узкоспециализирован. Конструктор вам скорее всего не нужен, попробуйте изменить нули в двух методах. Они вроде как отвечают за зазор, может поможет:

```
public class ThumbCreator {

    private Resources res;
    private BitmapDrawable left, right;

    public ThumbCreator(Resources r) {
        res = r;
        right = (BitmapDrawable) res
                .getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);
        right.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
        Bitmap rightBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res,
                android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);
        Matrix x = new Matrix();
        x.setScale(-1, 1);
        Bitmap leftBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(rightBitmap, 0, 0,
                rightBitmap.getWidth(), rightBitmap.getHeight(), x, true);
        left = new BitmapDrawable(res, leftBitmap);
        left.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
    }

    public Drawable createScrollBarThumb() {
        Drawable array[] = new Drawable[] {
                left.getConstantState().newDrawable(),
                right.getConstantState().newDrawable() };
        LayerDrawable layer = new LayerDrawable(array);
        layer.setLayerInset(1, right.getBitmap().getWidth(), 0, 0, 0);
        return layer;

    }

    public Drawable createZoomSBThumb() {
        BitmapDrawable mag = (BitmapDrawable) res
                .getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search);
        mag.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        Drawable array[] = new Drawable[] {
                left.getConstantState().newDrawable(), mag,
                right.getConstantState().newDrawable() };
        LayerDrawable layer = new LayerDrawable(array);
        layer.setLayerInset(2, mag.getBitmap().getWidth()
                + left.getBitmap().getWidth(), 0, 0, 0);

        return layer;
    }
}
```

Comment: layer.setLayerInset то что нужно, спасибо)